# преобразовать код из среды виндовс в среду линукс

Tags: php

этот код хорошо работает в виндовсе но отказывается работать в линуксе, как его можно переписать?

```
 $g = "name_" . Yii::$app->language;

 <?= $product->organ->$g ?>
```

Comment: Заходите на сервер, открываете лог ошибок и устраняете ошибки, которые указаны в логе.

Comment: В чем собственно ошибка? Я бы мог предположить про **short_open_tag**.

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object выдает эту ошибку

Comment: и я пытался переписывать полный вариант php echo, эффекта ноль

Comment: Вы уверены, что в органе Джи нужно искать?